# NetLogo - no more than 5 % of population has a certain value of variable

Tags: netlogo

How can I give each tick a random amount of turtles a change in a binary variable (1 or 0), whereas no more than 5 % of the existing population at all times has a value of 0 in that variable?

In other words, I wish to have that the total amount of turtles having a variable value of 0 is between 0 % or 5 % of the total amount of turtles at every tick.

How can I achieve this?

My code is:

```
to setup 
     create-turtles 100
     set var random 1 (only 5 % max shall have a 0 at start)
end

to start
    change
end

to change 
    let %draw (random 1)
    if (%draw < 0) … ; than I do not how to continue
end
```

Comment: count the number of turtles that already have value 0, subtract that from 5% of the total turtles and then do `ask n-of (1 + random N) turtles ...` where N is the results of the calculation

Comment: Thank you, JenB, for replying. How can I start with 5 % or less with a value of 0 for the variable on start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `n-of` primitive selects the specified number of agents. You want some number up to that, so you also need to randomly generate the number. Something like this:

```
to setup 
  create-turtles 100 [ set var 1 ] ; give them all value 1
  ask n-of random 6 turtles [ set var 0 ] ; randomly selects 0 to 5 turtles, assigns value 0
end
```

Comment: Awesome, JenB, this has helped me. :)