# NetLogo - random assignment of variable with threshold of 5 % for total population

Tags: netlogo

With regards to this question ([NetLogo - no more than 5 % of population has a certain value of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54901887/netlogo-no-more-than-5-of-population-has-a-certain-value-of-variable)), I would like to have a binary variable randomly assigned to a population where 5% or less of the population have a value of 0 for variable `var`.

Let us consider the following snippet:

```
  ifelse var = 0 [ ] ; if var already 0, do nothing
  [ ask n-of random 6 turtles [ set var 0 ] ] ; otherwise take random turtles and assign 0 to their var

  if number-novar > (count turtles * 0.05) [ ;; check if more then 5 % are with var = 0
    let %N (abs (count turtles * 0.05) - number-novar) ;; count number of turtles with var = 0, subtract from 5 % of the total turtles
    ask n-of (1 + random %N) turtles [ set var 0 ] ;; set random number turtles with var = 0 (less than or equal to 5 % of total population)
  ]
```

Each tick, the code shall check how many turtles have `var = 0`. If less then 5 % of the current total population of turtles have `var = 0`, it assigns a random amount of turtles to `var = 0` so that there are still only 5 % or less of the current total population with `var = 0`.

For example, if we have at tick 1, 100 turtles with 1 having `var = 0`, then the code can randomly assign between 0 to 4 turtles with `var = 0`. If 5 turtles have `var = 0` while the current total population is 100, the code does not assign any turtle with that value. If the current total population rises at tick 2 to 200 turtles in total with 1 turtles having `var = 0`, the code is allowed to randomly assign 0 to 9 turtles with a value of 0 for `var`.

There is a mistake somewhere in the above code, as it assign almost the total population with `var = 0` after tick 2 or 3, however I cannot find the error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `ifelse var = 0 [ ]` in your code, I assume that code is called by an `ask turtles`. If that's true, you have the turtles that have `var = 0` do nothing, but all other turtles will ask 6 other turtles to set their var to 0. Have a look at the toy model below for an example that maintains 5% of the turtles with var = 0 (more detail in comments):

```
turtles-own [ var ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 100 [
    set var 1
  ]
  ask n-of ( count turtles * 0.05 ) turtles [
    set var 0
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  decay
  print ( word "After decay, there are " count turtles with [ var = 0 ] " turtles with var 0" )
  maintain-5%
  print ( word "After maintenance, there are " count turtles with [ var = 0 ] " turtles with var 0" )
  tick
end

to decay
  ; Randomly have some var 0 turtles switch to var 1
  ask turtles with [ var = 0 ] [
    if random-float 1 < 0.2 [
      set var 1
    ]
  ]
end

to maintain-5%
  ; Get a count of turtles with var 0, and 5% of the current turtle count, and the different
  let n-novar count turtles with [ var = 0 ] 
  let max-novar ( count turtles * 0.05 ) 
  let dif max-novar - n-novar

  ; If n-novar is less than the max, ask 'dif' turtles with var 1 to switch to var 0
  if n-novar < max-novar [
    ask n-of dif turtles with [ var = 1 ] [
      set var 0
    ]
  ]
end
```